# Как в sql запросе с GROUP BY вычесть разность дат?

Tags: mysql, sql

Такая проблема:
Есть таблица `id(int),user_id(int),data(timestamp)`

```
1   1   2019-03-13 19:38:10 
2   1   2019-03-13 19:38:20
3   2   2019-03-13 20:00:10
4   2   2019-03-13 20:01:10
5   2   2019-03-13 20:00:30
```

Возможно ли сделать подобный запрос:

```
SELECT user_id, max(data)-min(data) result_data
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
```

Чтобы в сгрупированных записях высчитывало разность большей даты и меньшей.
именно этот запрос выводит какую-то ерунду 
Разница 8 секунд между двумя записями(всего две если записи), а результат 48.

Помогите пожалуйста, я не силен в sql запросах(

Comment: Привидите пример 3х записей в таблице вашей и что вы хотите получить в конечном итоге. Не совсем понятно тчо вы подразумеваете в столбце `data`

Comment: Добавил пример таблицы в вопросе

Comment: Вы не показали что хотите получить, т к мне не понятна логика такого запроса. Вы хотите вывести тоже самое, только чтобы вместо всех дат была разность максимальной и минимальной?

Comment: Я хочу вывести;  `1    0000-00-00 00:00:10                                    2     0000-00-00 00:01:00`  Простите за не форматированный комментарий.

Comment: вместо минуса DATEDIFF

Comment: Не совсем понятно, запрос такой:  `SELECT user_id, DATEDIFF(max(data),min(data)) result_data
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id`  выводит нулевой результат.  ` 1   0      2   0`

Comment: А может max и min не понимают что это дата?

Comment: Получилось если использовать TIMEDIFF, а нет единой функции чтобы и дату и время вычисляло сразу... чтобы не писать и DATEDIFF еще к TIMEDIFF ?

Comment: если хотите в формате даты и времени то нет. можно конечно вычислить в секундах и потом перевести их во время. правда оно будет в районе 1970 года и надо с часовым поясом будет разбираться